# How can I attach file with the latest date filename to an email from Share point folder using power automate?

Tags: email-attachments, power-automate

I have a SharePoint folder on the location ...

> sharepoint/sites/EmailAutomation/Documents/NewFileForAutomation

... where it contains excel files and name order is like (Sales 01-02-2023, Sales 02-02-2023, Sales 03-02-2023) I want to attach the file with the latest date to an email using power automate. I want to send this email once in a day.
My flow now looks like this. [image]

And my SharePoint folder looks like this [image]
I want to attach file with the latest date in this case "Sales 15-05-2023".
I am not able to get any clue how I can use any condition while choosing the file path in "Get file content using path". Is there any better way to resolve this issue? I am not able to find the similar issues.

Comment: Can you show us the inputs to the `Get file content using path` step?  Be sure to mask the `Site Address`.

Comment: Hi Skin, thank you for your comment. I think there should be a way to get all files name of SharePoint folder in a variable where we can apply logic to get file with the latest date and we can somehow attach file contain of that file to the email which can be sent once a day using recurrence. I  tried to  look different forum but couldn't find similar solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So all you need to do is use an expression to get the current date formatted and then pass that into the `Get file content using path` SharePoint operation ...

[image: Variable]

This is the expression that sits amongst the constant text ...

```
formatDateTime(utcNow(), 'dd-MM-yyyy')
```

Now, the only caveat here is that you may need to adjust the expression depending on your timezone and what you consider to be the current date when you flow runs.  I can't help you with that directly other than to point you towards the `convertFromUtc()` function and those like it.

**Result**

[image: Variable]